# How do I access this keyword In a different class

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

am having a problem trying to access this keyword in a different class using Java programming. I have tried Context, class.this but no help yet...

I have created a project using NetBeans gui builder, I want when i click button the form to get disposed...

Main class contains the click event for disposing the JFrame Form
BestQSystems.java:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
          CloseWindow.closeWindow(); 

   }
```

Class to close the JFrame:  CloseWindow.java

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.naming.Context;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Benson
 */
public class CloseWindow {
    public  static void closeWindow(){
        WindowEvent widnowEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(widnowEvent);
    }
}
```

Am having an error in this line  `WindowEvent widnowEvent = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);` Please advise me on how to access `this` keyword in a different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a reference to `this` to the other method. For example:

BestQSystems.java

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      CloseWindow.closeWindow(this); 
}
```

and in the CloseWindow.java

```
public class CloseWindow {
    public  static void closeWindow(BestQSystems ref){
        WindowEvent widnowEvent = new WindowEvent(ref, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am sorry would you please assist me here please.. suppose BestQSystems.java looked like this

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue This example will work only if the `BestQSystems` extends `Window` or a subclass of `Window`.

Comment: Okay I understand and I appreciate too much for your help... Another question though.. What if I want to pass `BestQSystems` reference to a different class from the `CloseWindow.java`... I mean suppose i have class Login containing functionality to login the users so after logging in the users the form to get disposed. So in BestQSystems.java I have called login function only.... Anything to add here

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue You can do the same thing, just change the class' constructor to accept a `BestQSystems` object as a parameter or change the method(s) of this class to accept such a parameter.

Comment: It has worked now... Nice for your help... Sorry for asking too much am a beginner in java programming... Nice for your help.. Am feeling proud now for knowing something new...